# How to group multiple imageview to have 1 tap gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift4, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have 5 imageviews in it. I need to get id of the imageview that is tapped. I tried adding tap gesture identifier and get sender's id, but I am not getting it.

What I have tried till now is as follows

```
@IBOutlet weak var userRateViewStar1ImageOutlet         : UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var userRateViewStar2ImageOutlet         : UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var userRateViewStar3ImageOutlet         : UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var userRateViewStar4ImageOutlet         : UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var userRateViewStar5ImageOutlet         : UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var userRateViewTextAreaOutlet           : UITextView!

@IBOutlet var starOutletCollectionOutlet                : [UIImageView]!


 @IBAction func starRatingAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    var tag = sender.view!.tag

    print(tag)

}
```

Basically I am trying to implement rate feature.

So can someone suggest me a way to implement this?

Comment: Why don't you try https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/floatratingview third party library ?

Comment: why don't you use `UIButtons`?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `UIButton`s.

If you want to use `UIImageView`s, here's how you do it:

1. Drag out a `UIImageView`.  In the *Attributes Inspector* on the right, set its image to your `star.png` image and check *User Interaction Enabled*.
2. Make four copies with copy (<kbd>command</kbd>-C) and paste (<kbd>command</kbd>-V).  Put them in a row, select them all and embed them in a `StackView` by selecting **Editor->Embed In->Stack View** from the menu.  Choose *Fill* Alignment and *Fill Proportionally* for Distribution.
3. Give your Stack View an *Aspect Ratio* constraint of `5:1`.  Give it constraints to place it on the page and to define its width.
4. Every image will need its own *Tap Gesture Recognizer* but they can all be hooked up to the same `@IBAction` routine.  Drag out *Tap Gesture Recognizer*s and drop them on each image.  Find the 5 *Tap Gesture Recognizer*s in the *Document Outline View* and <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from each of them to your `@IBAction` routine.
5. Assign tags `1` through `5` to your star images.
6. If you need `@IBOutlet`s to your `UIImageView`s, you can connect each of them to the same *Outlet Collection* such as your:

   ```
   @IBOutlet var starOutletCollection : [UIImageView]!
   ```

   then you can loop through them to change their images, for instance:

   ```
   // turn off all of the stars
   for star in starOutletCollection {
       star.image = UIImage(named: starOff.png)
   }
   ```